# Reachability for Markov process, continuous time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X$ be a strong Markov process in the continuous time with a state space $\mathbb R^n$. Consider a reachability problem for this process, i.e.
$$
v(x):=\mathsf P_x\{X_t\in A\text{ for some }0\leq t<\infty\}
$$
for an poen set $A$. In the discrete time there is an well-known (Bellman) integral equation on $v(x)$. It is necessary condition on $v$, the actual solution is given through the supremum over all solutions of this equation over function bounded with $0$ and $1$.

I am interested if there are similar results in the continuous time. In one paper I've read that if $X$ is a diffusion process then 
$$
\mathcal Av(x) = 0,\text{ for }x\in A^c
$$
and $v(x) = 1$ for $x\in\partial A$. Unfortunately, there were no strict conditions on the process $X$ as well as a strict proof of such a characterization.

I also put the question on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72370/reachability-for-markov-process-continuous-time).